# How to parse a LinkedIn page

Tags: php, html-parsing

May somebody help my how should I parse this link by curl?

https://www.linkedin.com/in/williamhgates/

And this is my codes:

Just run it and look at the result:

```
$url = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/williamhgates/";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: www.linkedin.com/in/williamhgates/'));
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);dd($output);die;
```

I just want to get whole of the source in a file but it shows:

```
Could not process this client request HTTP method request for URL
```

Comment: Maybe it is missing headers like useragents.

Comment: i try different ways with html_dom and curl but none of them works!

Comment: If you have file_get_html enabled in your php.ini you could use`$html = file_get_html(https://www.linkedin.com/in/williamhgates/');` and use the DOM class extract data from it.

Comment: i try it  before but i could't get the source at all.

Answer (score 2):

Linked in does not allow all crawlers except a few which send them traffic (Google bot, Bingbot, etc), They have explicitly blocked the User-agent. So it is not possible to make curl request to Linkedin page. 
But still anyhow you manage to crawl Linkedin, it could create legal issues for you. Hence, it’s better to leave Linkedin alone.

Answer (score 2):

Standard ways don't seem to work anymore with LinkedIn.
Even putting a LinkedIn page in an iframe doesn't work. You get a response saying `Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.linkedin.com does not permit cross-origin framing.`
Feed43 used to work until about 5 weeks ago, now it gets a `HTTP/1.1 999 Request denied` response.

There is an official LinkedIn plugin for getting a LinkedIn user profile widget on your site - https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/member-profile

And some other plugins as well - https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins

But that's all you get these days.